# Photons and gravitational wave

Tags: photons, gravitational-waves, shock-waves

Both photons and gravitational disturbances travel at $c$. Given that a photon does cause a tiny stress in spacetime due to its energy, and the propagation of this stress is at the same velocity as that of the photon, is a photon then accompanied by a corresponding "pressure wave" similar to that of a plane traveling at Mach 1? If so what effect would this, (which would effectively be a step in gravitational potential) have on whatever might absorb that photon?

Comment: Photons carry energy and momentum and pressure is just energy density, so...